# Measuring degree of difference?

Tags: statistical-significance

I am given area production and productivity of a fruit  in some places. The data belongs to the years 2012-13 and 2013-14. The data is collected by two different people. Obviously their sampling methods adopted (like the area(Ha) considered, tress opted, etc) are different and hence the final figures do not seem to be comparable at all. Now, how do I find the degree of difference? Can somebody please explain what degree of difference actually means. I did search for it and could not find anything. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: There is a nice formula of a dissimilarity function mentioned in "A Profile-Based Method for Authorship Verification". Give it a try...

Answer (score 0):

If your data are numeric, calculating the Euclidian distance will allow you to assess the distance between the two datasets.
The Euclidian distance will give you the shortest way between your datasets (in n dimension).

But it will maybe not be the most relevant because calculating distance between only two individuals will not tell you how important is this distance and how significative it is. So it is possible that if the data are measurable, a mean of the difference would be enough... and more comprehensible.

In fact a "degree of difference" means that you have a "referential" and that you look for the deviation level of the two datasets from this referential. One possibility is to choose one of the dataset as a referential (but it will be discussable), the other is just to measure the difference as proposed previously.

Comment: Thank you. Can you please explain with respect to my re framed question?